# How can I find the difference between rotations represented as angles in [0, 360]?

Tags: mathematics, rotation

What is the easiest way to find the difference between two 2D rotations/directions?

I want to test if one rotation is within 10° of another. I would just subtract, but there are some problems because I want to keep each rotation between 0 and 359. E.g. 0 is within 10° of 359, but simple subtraction would claim that they're 359 degrees apart.

Comment: You don't have to tag your questions only with the software you are using. I added some appropriate tags; it doesn't really seem like this question is specific to the framework anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### This requires simple modulo arithmetic.

1. Find the difference between two angles `t1` and `t2`.
2. Fix any angle differences that are greater than one full rotation.
3. If angle exceeds 180 degrees, compare in the ***other*** direction.

#### Pseudo Code:

```
d = mod (abs (t1 - t2), 360)

if (d > 180)
    d = 360 - d

if (d <= 10)
  "Hooray!!!"
```

Comment: Technically it may not require mod, but from your description in the actual question, I interpreted the situation as incoming angles may be outside the range [**0**, **360**] but you want to restrict the ***result*** to [**0**, **360**]. You can toss that part out if I misinterpreted your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

One easy way is to check if the difference is greater than 180 or less than -180. If it is, you can add or subtract 360 to one of the values and then get your difference.

Example:

```
if(r1-r2 > 180) //r1 > r2
     r1 = r1-360;
else if(r1-r2 < -180) //r1 < r2
     r1 = r1+360;
//then check the difference
diff = r1-r2;
```

Answer (score -1):

Note that above fails for `r1=720 and r2<=0`.
I would like this...

```
d = mod (r1 - r2), 360)
if(d >= 180) //r1 > r2
 d = d-360;
else if(d < -180) //r1 < r2
 d = d+360;
```